# Is there a way to "un-slice" an array on click?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Let's say I have a list of 10 items inside a div. When the page is loaded I only want the first 3 items to show up in the div, but when clicking on it, I want all 10 to show. If I click a second time they will go back to just showing 3.

I know that I can remove the items by using slice, but how do you get the items back after slicing them?

```
<template>
 <div>
   <div v-for="item in items">
      {{ item }}
   </div>
  <button @click="showItems">Hide/Show list</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
   data(){
      return {
         items: [ ...some list]
    }
   },
  methods: {
     showItems() {
        this.items.slice(0,2) /* I want this to either slice or show all on slick */
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Don't actually remove them from your list, just modify your render code to show only some of them

Answer (score 2):

You can create boolean variable which changes its state on click. Then you can create method or computed property, which returns an array. If your variable equals `true`, return the array itself, otherwise, return the sliced array)

Here is the example (didn't check, but should work):

```html
<template>
 <div>
   <div v-for="item in getItemsList()">
      {{ item }}
   </div>
  <button @click="showItems">Hide/Show list</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
   data(){
      return {
         items: [ ...some list],
         showAll: true,
    }
   },
  methods: {
      showItems() {
        this.showAll = !this.showAll;
      },
      getItemsList() {
        if (!this.showAll) {
          return this.items.slice(0, 2);
        }
        return this.items;
      }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The more easy way would be to **show/hide** instead of using the **slicing/unslicing** process.

Just use a condition to show all or only 3 by using a data property. Here is a way-

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      showAll: false,
      items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showItems() {
      this.showAll = !this.showAll;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <template v-for="(item, index) in items">
      <div v-if="!showAll && index < 3 || showAll">
        {{ item }}
      </div>
    </template>
    <button @click="showItems">Hide/Show list</button>
  </div>
</div>
```